# cypressError :You attempted to make a chai-jQuery assertion on an object that is neither a DOM object or a jQuery object

Tags: cypress, intercept, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

im trying to check if the respone body of a request to auth0 returns an object which contains an attribute access_toke.
this is my code:

```
When("I attemt to login with currect user credentials", () => {
  cy.intercept("https://punct-development.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token").as(
    "token"
  );
  cy.loginWith({ email: email, password: password });
  cy.wait("@token");
});

Then("Im succesfully logged in", () => {
  cy
    // .wait(14000)
    .get("@token")
    .its("response")
    .should("have.property", "body")
    .then((body) => {
      expect(body).to.have.attr("access_token");
    });
```

this is the tep where it fails, as you can see im getting the response body-
`expected { Object (access_token, id_token, ...) } to have attribute access_token` 
but when trying to verify it has an attribute access_token im getting the following error()-

````
The chai-jQuery assertion you used was:

  > attr

The invalid subject you asserted on was:

  > Object{5}

To use chai-jQuery assertions your subject must be valid.

This can sometimes happen if a previous assertion changed the subject.
cypress/integration/Login/login.ts:29:28
  27 |     .should("have.property", "body")
  28 |     .then((body) => {
> 29 |       expect(body).to.have.attr("access_token");
     |                            ^
  30 |     });
  31 | });
  32 | ```

[test run screenshot][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5fRC.png

any help will be much appreciated!
````

Comment: if your code is correct, you can try to replace the assertion with `cy.get(body).should('have,attr', "access_token")

Comment: @RosenMihaylov i changed it to - 
`Then("Im succesfully logged in", () => {
  cy
    // .wait(14000)
    .get("@token")
    .its("response")
    .should("have.property", "body");
  cy.get(body).should("have,attr", "access_token");
});
`
and now im getting the following error on my code - Cannot find name 'body'.
what is the currect syntax?

Comment: it is supposed to be chained as a `.then` like you did on your code

Comment: cy
    // .wait(14000)
    .get("@token")
    .its("response")
    .should("have.property", "body")).should('have,attr', "access_token")

Comment: @RosenMihaylov i got it working! i didnt replace the assertation as you suggested, just replaced `expect(body).to.have.property("access_token");`
`expect(body).to.have.attr("access_token");` 
do you think its a proper solution?

Comment: if it works - it is proper

Comment: this is the code now- 
@RosenMihaylov
`cy // .wait(14000) .get("@token") .its("response") .should("have.property", "body")).should('have,attr', "access_token")`
thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I think chai uses `.property` while cypress uses `.attr`. you can use the following chain because of the a `.should()` command returns the object it asserts, not the original element of the chain

```
cy
    // .wait(14000)
    .get("@token")
    .its("response")
    .should("have.property", "body")
    .should('have.attr', "access_token")
```